# React Native fetching API not showing the data http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

Tags: javascript, react-native

As the title said, why is my codes not showing the data from http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees although I've add the datasource and the URL correctly. Here's my code that you can review

https://gist.github.com/juskangkung/e33f51a5128de1bcffc443a39b44af50

Comment: post the log of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried your code every thing working fine the only change is
change

```
<Text  style={{ fontsize: 16, color: 'red' }} > {item.employee_salary} </Text>
```

to

```
<Text  style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'red' }} > {item.employee_salary} </Text>
```

You are passing fontSize prop incorrectly

and you don't have a name value in your data array, change `{item.name}` to `{item.employee_name}`

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah it works now after I run it locally, I ran it on snack expo before, maybe that is the issue why my app not showing the data from the API, and thanks for your correction xD